# @NotEmpty annotation validator for oneToMany

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

So I have the following Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Project")
public class Project implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PROJECT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int projectId;
    private String name;

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MANAGER_ID")
    @NotEmpty(message = "test")
    private User manager;
    ....
}
```

For some reason the "@NotEmpty" annotation gives the following error when
the input is blank:

*org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: com.springmvc.model.User.*

I am passing my values to the backend the following way:

```
<form:select path="manager" class="selectpicker form-control">
    <form:option value="" >Alle managers</form:option>
         <c:forEach var="manager" items="${managers}">
         <form:option value="${manager.userId}" >${manager.getUserDetail().firstName}               
                             ${manager.getUserDetail().lastName}</form:option>
         </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace @NotEmpty with @NotNull, that should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, however i'm currently getting the following error: Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type com.springmvc.model.User for property manager; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "".
I have edited my question to show my html

Comment: Yep thats because you are passing a String and you are trying to validate it against User object. That's entirely new problem.

Comment: I recommend creating a new question for that problem you are facing as its not necessarly Thymeleaf limited and closing this question off (still active as no accepted answer).